# Передняя панель нету звука в наушниках. (пробовал способы разные, не помогло)

Tags: linux, аудио, linux-mint

[image: Вот так выглядит]

Mute убрал, а вот полоски нету для регулировки звука, вообще не понимаю в чём проблема.

Comment: Скорее всего дешёвый кодек, нет у него контроля громкоски для наушников. Используется Master + PCM / ... Подробнее смотри в datasheet.

Comment: в прошлый раз когда ставил дистрибутив линукса была полоска эта, а сейчас просто 00. Даже в виндовс нужно ставить драйвер realtek hd версии 2.80 что бы нажать "Отключение функции определение гнёзд передней панели" или как-то так. Тогда передняя панель работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У себя в Mint  решил так:
Добавил в `default.pa` строчку
`set-sink-port 0 analog-output-headphones`